# How to pass props in my components inReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hello I have a collapse wrapper which has its Display state as true by default (I can't change that)
And a modal component which needs the display False when it opens.
I thought that setting the defaultOpen props as "false" would set the Display to false. But it doesn' work.
What do I do wrong ?
Here is the code  :

My Collapse wrapper :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ChevronUp from "react-feather/dist/icons/chevron-up";
import ChevronDown from "react-feather/dist/icons/chevron-down";
import { Collapse } from "reactstrap";
import "./style.scss";

class CollapseWrapper extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      display:
        props.defaultOpen === undefined ? true : props.defaultOpen,
      title: this.props.title,
    };
  }

  toggleContainer = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      display: !prevState.display,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { display, title } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.toggleContainer}>
          <div className="title-container">
            {display ? (
              <ChevronUp className="chevron" />
            ) : (
              <ChevronDown className="chevron" />
            )}

            <h2>{title}</h2>
          </div>
        </button>
        <Collapse isOpen={this.state.display}>
          {this.props.children}
        </Collapse>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default CollapseWrapper;
```

My modal :

```
import React from "react";
import { Modal } from "reactstrap";
import CollapseWrapper from "./CollapseWrapper";

class Mymodal extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal size="xxl" isOpen={isOpen} toggle={this.close}>
        <CollapseWrapper defaultOpen="false" title="More détails">
          Some content...
        </CollapseWrapper>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}

export default Mymodal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass boolean value inside the curly braces {} not in string.
Correct `defaultOpen={false}`
wrong `defaultOpen="false"`

```
<CollapseWrapper defaultOpen={false} title="More détails">
   Some content...
</CollapseWrapper>
```

Answer (score 1):

use arrow function in onClick event on your button

**replace**

```
onClick={this.toggleContainer}
```

**to**

```
onClick={() => this.toggleContainer()}
```

Comment: The two options do the same thing

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can use component life cycle method `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to solve this issue. Set your `display` state again when componentWillReceiveProps.

Solution:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   if (nextProps.defaultOpen !== this.state.display) {
     this.setState({ ...this.state, display: nextProps.defaultOpen });
   }
}
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated

Comment: @Charlote22 Yeah just now I checked. The life cycle hook is deprecated. Please check my another one answer. I hope, It will help you

Comment: Yeah it works with the false inside curly brakets. Thanks a lot ! I got to investigate that...